# Approximation via step functions through the conditional expectation on a sigma-field?

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, conditional-expectation, martingales

Suppose that $B$ is a Borel sigma field on $[0,1]$ and that we are working with Lebesgue measure. Also, suppose that $B_n$ is the smallest sigma field containing the intervals $I_j = [j2^{-n}, (j+1)2^{-n}]$ for $0 \leq j \leq 2^n -1$. Let $g$ be a function defined as $g : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $E(|g|^2) < \infty$. I am trying to write out $E( g  | B_n)$ in integral form and to argue that $E(g | B_n)$ will be the mean value on each interval. Does anyone have any idea how I can even start? thanks

Comment: I'm assuming $f$ and $g$ are meant to be the same? Also, by $\mathbb E[f]$ do you just mean $\int_{[0,1]} f\ \mathsf d\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure?

Comment: yes they are, just changed it! And yes, I do mean the expectation as you have written.

Comment: The setting can be more general. Consider a sigma field generated by a countable partition. Any function measurable w.r.t. this partition has to be constant on each element of the partition. Can you prove this?  Now consider $ E (f|B_n) $ this has to be constant on each small Intervall.  Can you see what constant it is, through the definition of conditional mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $f_n \to g$ in $L_2$, and that $f_n = \mathbb{E}(f \mid \mathcal{F}_n)$, show if $f$ continuous, then $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ with probability 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678375/if-f-n-to-g-in-l-2-and-that-f-n-mathbbef-mid-mathcalf-n-show)