# Underlying Random Variable of Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales, filtrations

Consider interval $[0,1]$ with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Lebesgue measure on it. It is known that $f$ is an integrable function on $[0,1]$. $\mathcal{F_n}=\sigma([\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}))$ where $1\leq k \leq 2^n$. For $n=1,2,...$, $x\in [\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n})$ define

$$\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F_n})(x):=\int_{\left[\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}\right)} 2^n f 
  \text{ d}\lambda$$

Then, what is $X$ ?

$\textbf{My try so far:}$

Straighforward for the definition of conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F_n})$, i found that $X=2^n f$. Yet, i then got confused, what is $n$ ? Shouldn't it be fixed $n$, right? Then, what is it?

Or am i missed something?

Comment: If you compute carefully $E(f\mid \mathcal F_n)$, you should realize that $X=f$ almost surely.

Comment: Hmm.. Where does the $2^n$ go, i wonder. .

Comment: Sorry but you really think that $$\int_{\left[\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}\right)} 2^n f \text{ d}\lambda$$ behaves like $$2^nf(x)$$ when $n\to\infty$ and $k/2^n\to x$?

Comment: I think you confused with $E[X|\mathcal F_n]$ with $E[X 1_{A_n}]$ where $A_n = [\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n})$ ? Iirc, $E[X|\mathcal F_n] = E[X|A_n]1_{A_n} + E[X|A_n^c]1_{A_n^c}$

Comment: @Did Dumb question: Can you answer without Lévy's upward theorem?

Comment: lalala.yeyeye, where did you get this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional expectation as a random variable new](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498931/conditional-expectation-as-a-random-variable-new)